# Middleman build - include coffee & less

Tags: build, preprocessor, middleman

Is it possible to `build` using [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), while including the coffee and less files? I want them to be in the build/ directory as well as the compiled ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think `middleman build` only compiles .coffee and .less, but you could use [Middleman's `after_build` callback](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom/#toc_9) to copy them yourself.

Symlinking the .coffee and .less files into the build folder might even work too.